# C# Index was out of range error when export to excel small amount of data

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview

I have a winform built in C# which can export data from SQL and then allows exporting it to Excel. The problem I faced is when I have only one row of data table wont be exported and I get an error that index is out of range. There is no problem whatsoever if there are two rows and more. Could you help me figure out what should be fixed? Debugging brings me to line -  saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Report - " + dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

```
     private void btnExport1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        this.Text = "Exporting...";

        _Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        _Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        _Worksheet worksheet = null;
        Range headersRow;
        Range allData;
        Range updateTimestamp;
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Report - " + dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        excel.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80;

        try
        {

            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
            worksheet.Name = "Summary";
            worksheet.Cells.WrapText = false;
            worksheet.Cells.Font.Name = "Text";
            worksheet.Cells.Interior.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            worksheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "@";


            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dataGridView1.Rows.Count ; rowIndex++)
            {
                for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < dataGridView1.Columns.Count +1; colIndex++)
                {
                    if (rowIndex == 0) 
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[rowIndex + 4, colIndex + 1] = dataGridView1.Columns[colIndex].HeaderText;
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[rowIndex + 4, colIndex + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex-1].Cells[colIndex].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }



            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    worksheet.Columns.AutoFit();
                    // worksheet.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 4;
                    // worksheet.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
                    worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"... logo.png", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 0, 0, 180, 39);

                    allData = worksheet.UsedRange;
                    allData.Borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range ur = worksheet.UsedRange;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range r = worksheet.Cells[4, ur.Columns.Count];
                    headersRow = worksheet.Range["A4", r];

                    headersRow.Cells.Font.Bold = true;
                    headersRow.Cells.Font.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
                    headersRow.Cells.Interior.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 055, 085);


                    worksheet.Cells[2, 5] = worksheet.Cells[5, 19];
                    worksheet.Cells[2, 5].Font.Bold = true;
                    worksheet.Cells[2, 4] = "Report date:";
                    worksheet.Cells[2, 4].Font.Bold = true;
                    worksheet.Cells[2, 4].HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                    updateTimestamp = worksheet.Range["S5", "S5"].EntireColumn;
                    updateTimestamp.Delete();
```

Comment: If there's only one row then dataGridView1.Rows[1] will give the error, as index is zero based, give a try with dataGridView1.Rows[0].

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: Thanks Bilal, tried, didnt help.  System.AtgumentOutOFRangeException - Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index.